# Facebook Web Context Authentication issue In IE

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-iframe

I am developing an asp.net web form application for Facebook iframe app. It contains two pages like List.aspx and View.aspx under same Master page.

I am using **FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated()** method to check whether the user is logged in to Facebook. When the List page is loaded it [FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated] returns true. When I navigate from List page to View page it returns false though i am connected to Facebook.

Even the **Request.Params["signed_request"]** is empty in View page.

**Moreover this happens in IE. In FF, Chrome and Safari its working fine.**

Help me to get rid of this issue.

Thanks.

**Edited on 10 Jan 2012**

I have used **FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated()** in Facebook Iframe Application to check whether the user is logged to Facebook or not. This check I am doing in Master Page Load event. But this is returning false in IE even though the user is logged in Facebook. Any alternative approach to this..

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to pass Signed request from List.aspx to View.aspx page either via post or get method by attaching whole signed request as querystring to url .
signed_request=Your signed request from previous form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Imran. The main issue is FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated() returning false always even I logged in to Facebook. This happens in IE alone. Is there anyway to solve this.

Comment: Did you mean it return false on both pages in IE? because you mentioned above that it returns true in List.aspx page. If it return false only on View page try sending Signed request from List page over to view page.

Comment: Imran, I have used " <input type="hidden" name="signed_request" value="<%= Request.Params["signed_request"]%>" />" in Master page..I think this causes me the issue. Because this hidden field has value on List page and it is empty for View page..Anything I am missing??

Comment: @Abirami How are you calling View.aspx?  I mean is it just link  you click on or is it button? I think I had similar issue once, I managed to solve it by adding signed request as parameter in URL on button click.

Comment: It just a link [anchor tag] I used to navigate to View page.. Is it enough to pass the signed_request in URL?

Comment: yes just try it out... something like View.aspx?signed_request=Your_Signed_Request in URL. Replace "Your_Signed_Request" with Request.Params["signed_request"] or similar